# Laravel API expired session

Tags: php, .net, laravel, api, session

In Laravel 5.4 I created some API on my routes/web.php. These API are called by .NET application. 
The first called API is the login, after that, I put in session some datas. 
Before to call other API, I check if the datas are in session, but after the first call (login), when I try to call the second one, the session seems to be flushed/expired.

Here my route code:

```
// API
Route::group(["prefix" => "api"], function() {
    // Login
    Route::post("login", "APIController@login");

    Route::group(["middleware" => "isNotAuthenticatedAPI"], function() {
        Route::group(["middleware" => "loginDBUser"], function() {
            // Importazioni
            Route::group(["prefix" => "importazioni"], function() {

                // Utenti
                Route::post("utenti", "APIController@importCustomers");
                // Attività (Abbonamenti)
                Route::post("attivita", "APIController@importSubscriptions");
                // Iscrizioni
                Route::post("iscrizioni", "APIController@importCustomersSubscriptions");
            });

            // Richieste
            Route::group(["prefix" => "richieste"], function() {
                // Ultima iscrizione
                Route::post("ultima_iscrizione/{subscription_external_id?}", "APIController@getLastCustomerSubscription");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Middleware isNotAuthenticatedAPI:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $res = [
            "result" => null,
            "errors" => [
            ]
        ];

        if (!$request->session()->get("user.api")) {
            $res["result"] = false;
            $res["errors"][] = [
                "code" => APIController::WARNING_SESSION_EXPIRED,
                "message" => trans("api.w_session_expired")
            ];
            return response()->json($res);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

My config/session.php:

```
'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,
```

I tried to put the route's code into routes/api.php, but the result doesn't change.

Comment: In Laravel5.4 to implement API you have to use api.php router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue using Session in API, please make sure that the client (your .NET application) store the cookie and include it in later requests.

A simple way to test if your problem is the cookie, try login your api in browser and call other api after that. If everything work well, then it's the cookie problem.

Comment: yes in my browser API work well, instead in my .NET application after each request session expired.

Comment: Yes, like I said, it's the cookie problem, so I suggest you use another way to log user in (like using a token, a header, etc...). If you want to stick with session, please continue searching about store cookie value in .Net client.

I don't know what your .NET client is so I couldn't help. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

please set property in config/session.php 
lifetime =value set to increase time out of session
or 
other this option with set middle ware handler set " config('session.lifetime') * 60; // min to hours conversion to solved this issue